# Low fps + very pixelated when playing steam games on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: steam, support, framerate

So I recently made the switch from windows 10 to Ubuntu, and when I booted up TF2 to see how it would run, I was getting an average of 5-10 fps! now mind you, on Windows 10, I would be getting around 70-100+ so this was a real shock to me. I then loaded up a game of Roblox to see if this was a sort of universal problem, and to my surprise, the fps was just fine there.

### Computer Specs:

Memory: 12GB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-9400T CPU @ 1.80GHz × 6

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)

Disk Capacity: 1.1 TB

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

OS Type: 64 Bit

GNOME Version: 42.1

---

If anyone knows the magic solution, I would be very thankful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYvS8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any solution, magic or otherwise.

[TF2](https://store.steampowered.com/app/440/Team_Fortress_2/) has been designed and optimized for Windows and DirectX.

All it takes is a cursory view of the system requirements and compare those between different OSes.

For the Windows version the **recommended (higher)** requirements are as low as **Windows 7**, a **Pentium 4 3.0GHz CPU or better**, **1GB RAM** and **DirectX 9.0c**.

Now compare the above with the "SteamOS + Linux" **minimum** requirements: **Ubuntu 12.04** (or newer or equivalent), an **Dual core from Intel** or **AMD at 2.8 GHz** (generations newer than the Pentium 4 required for Windows), **1GB RAM**, **nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11) GPUs** (note that Intel integrated graphics AREN'T mentioned) plus **OpenGL 2.1**.

From the above it should be easy to understand that (1) your system meets and largely exceeds the game's requirements for the Windows version but (2) comes short with the GPU (requires discrete graphics, Nvidia or AMD) for the Linux version.